# add failover in HA proxy in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, haproxy-ingress, automatic-failover

I am trying to implement failover https://www.haproxy.com/blog/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/ using HA proxy. My current environment is on Azure. I have deployed two application and an ingress controller and ingress. where I am able to navigate the traffic based on the route mentioned in the ingress and setup works fine as it is. now, I wanted to achieve, say I am navigating to sample.url and the url is down I want the request to be routed to anothersample.url. I can see from the example that was set up in the instance installation of HAProxy. how would I achieve something similar in kubernetes. Here is my ingress class.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: echo-ingress
    annotations:
        haproxy.org/path-rewrite: "/"
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /helloworld-one
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: helloworld-one
              port:
                number: 8080
        - path: /helloworld-two
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: hellowworld-two
              port:
                number: 8000
```

How to add backend snippet to block the IP or should it be in the ingress

```
backend-config-snippet: |
      http-send-name-header x-dst-server
      stick-table type string len 32 size 100k expire 30m
      stick on req.cook(sessionid)
```